# Unable to call PaintEvent in Qt (C++)

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I want to make a Qt application draw an Ellipse (a circle). I’m using a two file setup - `main.cpp` and `ui_mainwindow.h`.  I have defined a `QGraphicsView` and a `QPainter` on the `Ui MainWindow` class:

```
class Ui MainWindow {
public:
    ...
    QGraphicsView *radarGraphicsView;
    QPainter *radarPainter;
    ...
```

I have as well initialized the QGraphicsView:

```
void setupUi(QMainWindow *MainWindow) {
    ...
    radarGraphicsView = new QGraphicsView(centralWidget);
    ...
```

I have defined a paintEvent in the same class as well:

```
void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event) {
    radarPainter = new QPainter(radarGraphicsView);
    radarPainter->setPen(Qt::green);
    radarPainter->drawEllipse(10, 10, 10, 10); }
```

Anyways, in result I cannot see any ellipse being drawn in the QGraphicsView, and I assume I’m supposed to call the paintEvent, but I’ve found no such example in a setup like mine (Qmake). How am I supposed to call the paintEvent for the Ellipse to be drawn?

Comment: Hi there, did you try to follow the example in the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qpainter.html#details)? i.e. destructing the painter after each event.

Comment: @TrebuchetMS I did attempt to follow the example and my code that I have submitted on the question is the closest I’ve got with my configuration.

Comment: Well, if you're calling `new` on each event... try calling `delete radarPainter`? Unless you're using your `radarPainter` elsewhere in mainwindow, keep it as a normal variable.

Comment: @TrebuchetMS Thank you for the reply but I’m pretty sure this isn’t important at the moment since the ellipse isn’t being drawn at all.

Answer (score 2):

`void paintEvent(QPaintEvent*) override;` is a virtual member function of `QWidget` class and it's used to draw on widgets derived from `QWidget`. In case you want to draw an ellipse into `QWidget` you have to override that like following.

```
class MyClass : public DerivedFromQWidget
{
  ...

  protected: // or any other
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event){
      QPainter painter(this);
      painter.setPen(Qt::black);
      painter.setBrush(Qt::red);
      painter.drawEllipse(ellipse);

      ...

      DerivedFromQWidget::paintEvent(event);
    }

  ...

};
```

The `paintEvent` function will be called continuous while it's implementer is shown.

I believe the following class can help you to solve the problem

```
// ellipse_drawer.h

class EllipseDrawer : public QWidget
{
public:
  EllipseDrawer(QWidget* parent = nullptr);

protected:
  void paintEvent(QPaintEvent*);
};

// ellipse_drawer.cpp

EllipseDrawer::EllipseDrawer(QWidget* parent)
  : QWidget(parent)
{
  setFixedSize(200, 200);
}

void EllipseDrawer::paintEvent(QPaintEvent*)
{
  QPainter painter(this);
  painter.setPen(Qt::black);
  painter.setBrush(Qt::red);
  painter.drawEllipse(rect());
}

// my_main_window.h

class MyMainWindow : QMainWindow
{
  MyMainWindow(QWidget* parent = nullptr);
};

// my_main_window.cpp

MyMainWindow::MyMainWindow(QWidgat* parent)
  : QMainWindow(parent)
{
  setCentralWidget(new EllipseDrawer());
}

// in main.cpp

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  MyMainWindow widget;
  widget.show();
  return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: “QPainter radarPainter(this)” gives me an error “no matching function for call to ‘QPainter::QPainter(Ui_MainWindow*)’”, but the error is skipped with “QPainter radarPainter(radarGraphicsView);”, however what should be instead the DerivedFromQWidget?

Comment: do you need `QGraphicsView` at all? you can simply draw your ellipse right on your widget. Argument for `QPainter`'s constructor must be `QPaintDevice` but your class `UI_MainWindow` seems to be a base class. that's why you're getting that error

Comment: http://pastebin.com/u7qQ3Vwd tried to draw directly on the widget but no results. Anyways, the function is not called anywhere, where am I supposed to call it?

Comment: @user10904879 please review the answer

Comment: I can see the update, thanks, so I’m supposed to create two new files? Do I include them in main.cpp?

Comment: you don't have to manually call the `paintEvent` function, because design of `Qt` is good enough to call it instead of you. the only stuff you have to do is to place your widget that implements the function into visible space of your screen. that will cause to continuous call of `paintEvent` function

Comment: you can simply put all this code into `main.cpp` file to just see the result. it isn't full solution to your problem, but it could be good guide for you

Comment: Thanks! “class EllipseDrawer : public QWidget” gives me an error “new types may not be defined in a return type”, though

Comment: Nevermind, thanks! The problem is that the circle becomes a new window

Comment: Hey, how do I change the parent to the ui_mainwindow.h centralWidget?

Comment: why do you want to change the parent of centralWidget?

Comment: My bad, of the “nullptr” to centralWidget, since the code just makes a new window with the ellipse

Comment: anyway. what is the reason for changing parent of centralWidget?

Comment: no reason for that, my bad, missed a few words in the sentence. All I wanna do is to make the ellipse in the existing window instead of a new one.

Comment: you said that my example gives an error. try to separate code blocks into files as i commented, be careful for every `;` to be put in place. that strategy can be used in `QMainWindow` as well. try it. but I will recommend you to create a `QMainWindow` derived object and set centralWidget for that a new instace of `EllipseDrawer`

Comment: fixed the error buddy, also yeah only the window problem now

Comment: review the new changes. I made an example for importing the class into `QMainWindow` as a centralWidget

Comment: Thanks for updating! Your supplied code gives me errors, though: http://pastebin.com/XGmhrHCc . The errors are: http://pastebin.com/p6epXQDA

Comment: Sorry but I'm not familiar with terminal build process. But I'm pretty sure, that my code is working one. Try to solve the build process problem yourself

Comment: @user10904879 did my answer answered your question? if so, please accept it